# How to put data in L2 cache with A72 Core?

Tags: linux, caching, embedded-linux, arm64, cortex-a

I have an array of data that looks like this :

```
uint32_t data[128]; //Could be more than L1D Cache size
```

In order to do computation on it, I want to put the data as close as possible to my computing unit so in the L2 Cache.

My target runs with a linux kernel and some additionnal apps

I know that I can get an access to a certain area of the memory with mmap and I have succesfully done it in some part of my available memory shared between cores.

**How to do the same thing but in L2 Cache area ?**

I've read part of gcc documentation and AArch64 assembly instruction set but cannot figure out the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do the same thing but in L2 Cache area ?

Your hardware doesn't support that.

In general, the ARMv8 architecture doesn't make any guarantees about the contents of caches and does not provide any means to explicitly manipulate or query them - it only makes guarantees and provides tools for dealing with *coherency*.

Specifically, from section D4.4.1 "General behavior of the caches" of [the spec](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest):

```
[...] the architecture cannot guarantee whether:

• A memory location present in the cache remains in the cache.
• A memory location not present in the cache is brought into the cache.

Instead, the following principles apply to the behavior of caches:

• The architecture has a concept of an entry locked down in the cache.
  How lockdown is achieved is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED, and lockdown might
  not be supported by:

  — A particular implementation.
  — Some memory attributes.

• An unlocked entry in a cache might not remain in that cache. The
  architecture does not guarantee that an unlocked cache entry remains in
  the cache or remains incoherent with the rest of memory. Software must
  not assume that an unlocked item that remains in the cache remains dirty.

• A locked entry in a cache is guaranteed to remain in that cache. The
  architecture does not guarantee that a locked cache entry remains
  incoherent with the rest of memory, that is, it might not remain dirty.

[...]

• Any memory location is not guaranteed to remain incoherent with the rest of memory.
```

So basically you want cache lockdown. Consulting [the manual of your CPU](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100095/0003/Level-2-Memory-System/About-the-L2-memory-system) though:

```
• The Cortex-A72 processor does not support TLB or cache lockdown.
```

So you can't put something in cache on purpose. Now, you might be able to *tell* whether something has been cached by trying to observe side effects. The two common side effects of caches are latency and coherency. So you *could* try and time access times or modify the contents of DRAM and check whether you see that change in your cached mapping... but that's still a terrible idea.
For one, both of these are destructive operations, meaning they will change the property you're measuring, by measuring it. And for another, just because you observe them *once* does not mean you can *rely* on that happening.

Bottom line: you cannot guarantee that something is held in any particular cache by the time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Cache - is not a place where data should be stored, it's just... cache? :)

I mean, your processor decide which data it should cache and where (L1/L2/L3) and logic depends on CPU implementation.

If you wanted to, you could try to find the algorithm of placing and replacing data in cache and play with this (without guaranties, of course) by using dedicated instructions to prefetch your data and then maintain the cache with non-caching instructions for your other program.

Maybe for modern ARM there are easier ways, I spoke from x86/x64 perspective, but my whole point is "are you really sure that you need this"?
CPU's smart enough to cache the data which they need and they do it better and better year by year.

I'd recommend you to use any profiler that can show you cache misses to be sure than your data is not presented in the cache already.
If it don't, the first thing to optimize - is an algorithm. Try to figure out why there was a cache miss - maybe you should load less data in loop by using temp variables, for example, or even unroll the loop manually to control where and what being accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I know that data should not be stored in cache however, I need to benchmark an algorithm with input data at least in the intercore SRAM (i.e. Level 3 cache) and in L2 or L1 if possible. I can store them initially in DDR and then prefetch them in cache, however I have to verify that the data is indeed in cached before the algorithm runs.
I use _builtin_prefetch() from gcc but I can't figure how to check if they are cached.
My algorithm is optimized and the data access time is now the bottleneck. I can't use profilers that slows my program, do you have any to recommend ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't check if the data cached directly, only by cache miss statistics. Unfortunately, I working with Windows-x64 and can't give you recommendations for your stack.

Comment: @JacobB: I think what most people do is just to explicitly read the entire data set (i.e. load every word) before starting the benchmark run.  That means it all made it into L2 cache (and L1 besides), and if the whole set fits in L2 and you didn't do any significant memory access in between, you presume it is mostly going to still be there.  Just make sure there is an appropriate barrier on the code that reads the timer, so that the loads have really all completed before you "start the clock".

Comment: Adding my 2 cents. Not sure about A72, but A53 (ARMv8 arch) has special cache debug registers that allow to check cached addresses and data. Don't think that these registers available in user space (EL0), but should be available in kernel mode (EL1)

Comment: Thank you all
I will check if A72 has cache debug registers.
@NateEldredge, I have tried this and this seems to work, I just don't have any proof that every bit is cached that what is problematic in my context.

Comment: @JacobB: Right, but I don't think most people expect to have literal proof; benchmarking is noisy anyway, and so people usually consider it sufficient to be able to say that with high probability, the majority of the data set is in cache.  Even if you could get a snapshot of cache contents at a given instant, without locking mechanisms, it would be instantly stale; the machine could have evicted some lines between the moment when you did the check and the actual start of the test.